# Android Application getting username and password from SMS

Tags: android, sms

I have an android's application which needs username and password, my server sends the username and password to mobile via SMS.

I was looking for a way through which my application can read the SMS and can automatically configure itself with username and password in the settings rather than manually configuring it in the settings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Receiver.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class Receiver   extends BroadcastReceiver     
{

  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;         
    if (bundle != null)
    {
      //---retrieve the SMS message received---
      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
      for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
      {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                

        checkSMS(context, msgs[i]);
      }
    } 
    }

  void checkSMS(Context context, SmsMessage sms) 
  {
    String msg = sms.getMessageBody().toString();

  }

}
```

Comment: I am calling this as following, it only execute once and doesn't stay alive for 20 seconds or even more. Message will be sent within 20 seconds I want that it should be keep on listening for at least 20 seconds. `sms.sendTextMessage("XXXXXX", null, "MSG", null, null);
 Receiver rc=new Receiver();
rc.onReceive(getContext(), new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));`

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean but I think you are doing something wrong, you don't need to create new Receiver class and call rc.onreceive. Create a Receiver.java as the sample I gave you and add your manifest this class as I wrote on my answer. Than whenever phone gets an sms from someone, android telephony framework will call your applications Receiver classes OnReceive method even you application is not open. and you can do whatever you want on checksms function.

Answer (score 1):

use SMS broadcast listener with high priorty and on rcv check if it came from the number which your server is using to send SMS if yes then extract the information from SMS text and and update the configurations of your app accordingly and you can even use abortBroad cast method if you want that SMS should not shown in native SMS app

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide with me with some sample code i.e. an over view ?

Comment: here is simplest code to receive SMS http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/receiving-sms-using-broadcastreceiver.html and this link also having good detail http://boomtech.in/entries/general/sms-toast--using-broadcast-receiver---retrive-contact-information